# XeLaTeX doesn't work latex editors

Tags: xetex, kile

So,I have this xelatex version:

```
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020)
kpathsea version 6.3.2
Copyright 2020 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 65.1; using 65.1
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.10.1; using 2.10.1
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.13; using 1.3.13
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 2.6.4; using 2.6.4
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
Compiled with poppler version 0.68.0
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.11.0; using 2.13.1
```

But when I use the xelatex compiler option in kile or texstudio, it does not generate the pdf, in texstudio, the logscreen says:

```
Error: impossible to run command: xelatex -synctex=1 -interaciotn=nonstopmode "filename".tex
```

and in kile:

```
[XeLaTeX] Failed to start
```

I think it is not a PATH problem since the command is reconized in the terminal in any directory and I made sure to edit my PATH env variable to add the */usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux* directory

edit-1: interaction*

Comment: Do you get the error when you launch `Kile` or `TeXStudio` from terminal?

Comment: `-interaciotn` should be `interaction`.

Comment: No, @Tanvir . If I launch  the programs from terminal, xelatex works fine.

Comment: @Bernard this didn't solved the problem but thanks for pointing it out! :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix to your issue would be to replace the `xelatex` command in `Kile Build` menu with `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/xelatex`.
This is how it would look
[image]

Or

To make `Kile` (launched by clicking the software logo) recognize the exact path of texlive 2020 packages, do the following:

Add `PATH` of texlive 2020 to `/etc/login.defs` file.  In the file do the following changes:

```
 ENV_SUPATH  PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

 ENV_PATH    PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```